# Is there any Linux based ubuntu installer like wubi?

Tags: live-usb, wubi, live-cd

I have a kali live CD and I'd like to install ubuntu on my HD, unfortunately I have no USB drives so I was wondering if there is some wubi like installer for Linux, or an alternative way to install ubuntu when all I have is a live CD and an empty HD

Comment: question: empty hd? WUBI requires windows to already be installed :)

Comment: UNetbootin will do a temporary install to hard drive that can be used to install an OS the next time the computer is booted. No USB required,

Answer (score 1):

[Wubi for Ubuntu 19.10](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases).

- md5sum: c87ac6368eaba0f5465270f39cc8f9d3
- sha256sum: fa7b1a79633bb766aca7062d36ee3ec0c1d3d79b47dec98d962141d5538f5dad

**Supported features:**

- Version 19.10 with automatic download
- Ubuntu (64 bit only), Kubuntu (*) (64 bit only), Ubuntu Studio (64 bit only), - Ubuntu MATE (64 bit only), Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin (64 bit only), Ubuntu Budgie (64 bit only)
- various distros/versions with manual download (desktop environments "Wubi", "Wubi lz", "Wubi EFI", "Wubi MD5", "Wubi gz", "Wubi SHA256")
- UEFI (64 bit + 32 bit), legacy BIOS
- Fast Startup and Hibernate
- Secure Boot
- Parted 3.2
- MMC + NVMe devices
- package lupin-support (for Lubuntu and Ubuntu Studio)
- disk sizes > 30 GB